# Java encoding issue with ├ └

Tags: java, encoding

If I print

```
System.out.println("│ ├── └──");
```

I see only question marks (???). Seams that this is some king of encoding problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: How are you running your code? What is encoding of your files?

Comment: I run it through the bash + Eclipse + IDEA terminal. And encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: What’s your source file’s encoding? What’s the system locale (`echo $LANG`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas how to fix this?

There are two *possible* causes of your problem:

1) It could be happening when you edit compile source code.  The compiler could be reading the source code using a different file encoding to the one that you are using when you edit it.  If you don't specify a source file encoding, the compiler will use a platform-specific default, and that might not be the right one.

The fix for this is to adjust your compiler settings to specify the correct source file encoding.  How you do that will depend on how you are compiling.  If you are compiling from the command line using `javac`, use the `-encoding` option.

Alternatively, a workaround for this problem is to replace the offending in your source code with Unicode escapes.  For example:

```
String s = "\u251c";
```

should give you a one character string consisting of a "├" character.  I would recommend the workaround.  Source code that includes non-ASCII characters is always going to be sensitive to how you edit and compile ... and that is not a good thing.

2) It could be happening because there is a mismatch between your Java runtime platform's default output encoding and the actual encoding of whatever is displaying the output.

The fix for this is one of:

- change the encoding for the display,
- override the default encoding for the JVM (e.g. using `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`), or
- change your code to output using a specific encoding.

Which is best depends on the circumstances; e.g. why things are "wrong" in the first place.

---

It is worth running this test application from the command prompt to see if the problem exists their too. If it does, then redirect standard output to a file, and use a hex dump utility (e.g. od on Linux) to see how the characters are encoded. That will help you distinguish causes 1) and 2) above.

(It is also possible that you have both problems ...)

Answer (score 3):

Use the UTF-8 codes instead of the actual characters. For example ├ is \u251c.

Here is a link that will help you convert characters to corresponding codes: http://www.cylog.org/online_tools/utf8_converter.jsp

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of the java file (editor( and the encoding that the javac compiler better both use UTF-8. This generally is a IDE or project setting.

One might check that both encodings are equal, by the u-escaping of those chars: `\u251C` etcetera,

System.out must use the operating system encoding. If that encoding cannot convert those characters, one might see a `?`. If the console is a console *emulation*  of the IDE, you might search the setting of that encoding. Also check that the console font contains those graphic chars. Running the IDE with `java -Dfile.encoding UTF-8` might help.

***In your case:*** Strange. Check the source encoding with gedit, dump `System.getProperty("file,encoding")`.